Send logs from AWS Lambda to backend using opentelemetry collector
I am trying to send logs from AWS lambda (which is printed to stdout) to aws opensearch backend using opentelemetry collector.
My configuration looks like this :

I have central otel collector running inside vpc
I followed this documentation - https://opentelemetry.io/docs/faas/lambda-collector/


2a. I added otel collector lambda layer to my function from here -- https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda/releases
2b. I created custom otel collector config file at root of the project with following value :

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: '0.0.0.0:4317'
      http:
        endpoint: '0.0.0.0:4318'

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: http://<my-central-otelcol-endpoint>:4318/v1/logs
    tls:
      insecure: true

service:
  pipelines:
    logs:
      receivers:
        - otlp
      exporters:
        - otlphttp
  telemetry:
    metrics:
      address: localhost:8888


2c. I setup this env var in lambda -- OPENTELEMETRY_COLLECTOR_CONFIG_FILE = /var/task/collector.yaml

My question is - is it even possible to send logs directly from aws lambda to other place using opentelemetry collector like this.
Also,

I do not want to use opentelemetry SDK and its logging APIs inside code.
and do not want to use cloudwatch logs subscription filter to stream logs to opensearch from cloudwatch logs


Your configuration isn't valid. You should replace endpoint: http://<my-central-otelcol-endpoint>:4318/v1/logs -> endpoint: http://<my-central-otelcol-endpoint>:4318. The target base URL to send data to (e.g.: https://example.com:4318). To send each signal a corresponding path will be added to this base URL, i.e. for traces "/v1/traces" will appended, for metrics "/v1/metrics" will be appended, for logs "/v1/logs" will be appended. https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/exporter/otlphttpexporter/README.md

Not sure I understand how your goal relates to the config. The logs pipeline you have defined here says that you're receiving logs inbound via OTLP but you say you expect to receive the logs from stdout. Can you help me understand how that fits together, please?

Try a service like https://lumigo.io/
